# Check if type is declared as a meta type system (for SFINAE)

Tags: c++, qt, sfinae, type-traits, enable-if

To make a case distinction for a parameter `t` of type `T` using SFINAE, I want to know if the statement

```
QVariant::fromValue(t);
```

and / or

```
QVariant::value<T>();
```

compiles. If the one compiles, the other one does too, unless you hack the meta type system. They compile if and only if `T` has been declared using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(T)`.

Very simple usage example, where one wants to print the type of a value by simply qDebugging a variant-wrapped equivalent, if and only if supported by the meta type system (I don't need this, but this shows the problem in a minimal example):

```
template<class T>  // enable if T NOT registered in the Qt meta type system
void print(const T &t) {
    qDebug() << t;
}

template<class T>  // enable if T registered in the Qt meta type system
void print(const T &t) {
    qDebug() << QVariant::fromValue<T>();
}
```

I know several (yet similar) possibilities to do so, but all of them introduce some helper structs, complicated enable_if etc. Now I know that there is `QTypeInfo` which, I guess, already provides something like an "is declared in the Qt meta type system" type trait. However, this class is not documented and thus it's not suggested to be used in long term and productive code, as it might change between Qt versions.

Is there a very simple way (simpler than with a "checker" + enable_if) to check in a SFINAE specialization if a type `T` is supported by QVariant?

Please note that the solution still should be *portable* between different Qt versions (Qt4 and Qt5 might use a different `QTypeInfo` definition). However, I use C++11, so I have access to `std::enable_if` for example.

The "non-portable" way is to use the internal definition of `QMetaTypeId2<T>::Defined` in an `enable_if` (it's an enum value defined as either 0 or 1). Thus, a working solution would be:

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!QMetaTypeId2<T>::Defined>::type
print(const T &t) {
    qDebug() << t;
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<QMetaTypeId2<T>::Defined>::type
print(const T &t) {
    qDebug() << QVariant::fromValue<T>();
}
```

However, since `QMetaTypeId2` is not documented and only internal stuff, it should not appear in client code.

Comment: Correct me if I'm mistaken: you want to know in **compile-time** did  some type registered in Qt-meta-system in **run-time** ??? If yes - it 's nonsense

Comment: No. I mean "declared", i.e. there is an `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(T)` present. Sorry, I'll correct it.

Comment: The nearest I can find is `qMetaTypeId<T>()`, but it causes a compiler error if `T` is unregistered - not so good.

Comment: @cmannett85 Actually, this is the other solution and the one which I am currently using. However, I thought about something *like* `QMetaTypeId2` which is *documented* and can be used straight away. Such a thing doesn't seem to exist, so I have to put the SFINAE boilerplate around `qMetaTypeId<T>()` to turn the "compilability" into a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a wrapper that will help you. The best I can think is to have several definitions, based on the [version](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtglobal.html#QT_VERSION) of Qt:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_registered
{
    enum
    {
        value = 
#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000 // Qt 5.0.0
            QMetaTypeId2<T>::Defined
#elif QT_VERSION >= 0x040000 // Qt 4.0.0
            QMetaTypeId2<T>::Defined
#endif
    };
};
```

That's not aesthetic, but that is functionnal, and in your code you can use `is_registered<T>::value` without having to worry about the version of Qt. Also, I don't have Qt5 for the moment, so I cannot tell you whether `QMetaTypeId2<T>::Defined` is correct for it (although I think it is).

---

It is impossible to use `qMetaTypeId<T>()` to check if a type was registered. In fact, the expression `qMetaTypeId<T>()` is always valid, no matter the type. If it is not registered, the *body* of the function will not compile (to be more precise: in Qt 4 and 5 (for the moment), `qMetaTypeId<T>()` only calls another function that does not compile if the type is not registered. Thus, you cannot use SFINAE to test it. As a result, the code leemes gave in his (now deleted) answer [will not work as expected](http://ideone.com/jcv6a2).

The code was:

```
struct _test_is_declared_metatype
{
    template<class T>
    static auto test(T* t) -> decltype(qMetaTypeId<T>(), std::true_type());

    static std::false_type test(...);
};

template<class T>
struct is_declared_metatype : decltype(_test_is_declared_metatype::test<T>(0))
{
};
```

Why this won't work ? The intention was that because calling `qMetaTypeId<T>()` on a non-registered type results in a compile error, *"SFINAE would exclude the first function when the type is not registered"*. The problem here is that `qMetaTypeId<T>()` is always a valid expression, so `qMetaTypeId<T>(), std::true_type()` is too, and `decltype(qMetaTypeId<T>(), std::true_type())` is perfectly defined (with the value `std::true_type`).
This because the compilation error of `qMetaTypeId<T>()` stems in the *body* of the function, not in its prototype (by the way the code will compile only if the function in the `decltype` is declared and correctly called, ie no template arguments for a non-template function for example).
Thus, because this overload of `test()` is more specific than the variadic one, it will always be choosed, hence it will always 'return' that the type is registered; you can see it in the following test code:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------
// qmetatype.h simplification -------------------------------
// ----------------------------------------------------------

template<typename T>
struct metatype
{
 enum { defined = 0 };
};

template<typename T>
struct metatype2
{
 enum { defined = metatype<T>::defined };
 static inline int id() { return metatype<T>::id(); }
};

template <typename T>
inline int metatypeId(
    T * /* dummy */ = 0
)
{
    return metatype2<T>::id();
}

#define register_meta_type( _type_ )  \
 template<>                           \
 struct metatype< _type_ >            \
 {                                    \
  enum { defined = 1 };               \
  static int id()                     \
  {                                   \
   /* Run-time registration in Qt */  \
   return __COUNTER__;                \
  };                                  \
 };



// ----------------------------------------------------------
// ----------------------------------------------------------
// ----------------------------------------------------------

class TestA {};
register_meta_type(TestA)

class TestB {};

class TestC {};
register_meta_type(TestC)

class TestD {};


#include <type_traits>

struct _test_is_declared_metatype
{
 /*
   metatypeId<T>() is always a valid expression. So this overload is
   always taken
 */
    template<class T>
    static auto test(T* t) -> decltype(metatypeId<T>(), std::true_type());

    static std::false_type test(...);
};

template<class T>
struct is_declared_metatype : decltype(_test_is_declared_metatype::test<T>(0))
{
};

#include <iostream>
#define PRINT_DEF( _type_ )  std::cout << #_type_ << " registered ? " << is_declared_metatype< _type_ >::value << "\n";
int main()
{
 std::cout << std::boolalpha;
 PRINT_DEF(TestA);
 PRINT_DEF(TestB);
 PRINT_DEF(TestC);
 PRINT_DEF(TestD);
}
```

You might want to [read more about SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error). Also, you can [read `qmetatype.h` here](http://pastebin.com/nQSvy0XB).

Comment: Thank you. It's correct for both, that's not the point. The point is: it's undocumented, which means that it can change in the future more likely than documented stuff. On the other hand, for example `qMetaTypeId<T>()` is documented and provides also a check. It fails to compile if `T` is not registered. That means that a SFINAE trick is required to map the "compilability" into a boolean compile-time value.

Comment: I looked in the source, and for me qMetaTypeId() cannot be used with SFINAE. Also, undocumented code in Qt 4.x will be present in these versions 'forever', so using preprocessor is ok, I think.

Comment: Why do you think can't `qMetaTypeId()` be used with SFINAE? I'm new to SFINAE, so maybe I overlooked some detail.

Comment: +1, thanks for clarifying. I thought my tests were successful, damnit. I guess I remembered back when I used `QMetaTypeId2<T>::Defined`, which worked (as in the question). Sorry to bother you with this. PS: I used the trailing return type because 1. then it is consistent with the first case and 2. because the original code snippet wasn't mine.

Comment: PPS: I deleted my answer, maybe you want to edit yours (so not reference my answer but tell why we can't use SFINAE to check if such a function call will compile).

Comment: Done. Can you give me the link where you found the "SFINAE trick" you posted ? Hope the explanations are clear, feel free to comment if it is not the case ;)