# Trailing return type with decltype boolean arithmetic

Tags: c++, c++11

I decided to have a play with trailing return types with delctype shown below:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto Add(T t, U u) ->decltype(t,u)
{
    return t + u;
}
```

this works perfectly fine if I send in integers or doubles e.g.

```
Add(10,11); //21
Add(5.35,2.22); //7.57
```

but then I asked myself will this work on boolean arithmetic?

```
Add(true,true); // = 1 + 1 = 1;
Add(true, false); // = 1 + 0 = 1    
Add(false, false); // = 0 + 0 = 0;
```

In this case it worked fine but then I decided to try the following instead:

```
->decltype(t + u)
```

Which gave me the result:

```
Add(true,true); // = 1 + 1 = 2;
Add(true, false); // = 1 + 0 = 1
Add(false, false); // = 0 + 0 = 0;
```

I'm presuming the decltype(t+u) is deducing the return type as int instead of bool? why is this? and is there a hierarchy of types decltype will choose?

Comment: because the decltype of a sum of bools that are automatically promoted to integer is an integer?

Comment: @Jefffrey sorry fixed :)

Comment: @dionadar yeah this is what I thought, just a small query really.

Comment: Actually, `decltype(t,u)` is `decltype((t,u))` is `decltype((u))` is `bool&` and the instantiation of `Add` should fail because the `return` tries to bind a temporary to a non-const lvalue reference. See [here (freshly asked)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186377/meaning-of-decltype-with-more-than-one-argument) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044514/what-is-decltype-with-two-arguments).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Because the type of the expression is `int` and not `bool`

Long answer: By calling `Add(true, true)` your template type parameters `T` and `U` are deduced to be bool. Therefore, the type of  the expression `t, u` is `bool`. Note that the comma in this expression is the comma operator, as pointed out by @ccom.

Since you cannot arithmetically add bools (the symbol `+` is sometimes used in logic to denote the or operator which is `|` in c++), c++ will automatically promote both bools to integers and then perform the addition.

In the case `decltype(t, u)`, your return type is bool, and therefore another implicit cast happens, forcing your integer of 2 to become a boolean value (true, or 1, when converted back to int)

In the case `decltype(t + u)` the return type is the type of the expression (`int`) and therefore the final conversion is simply not done - giving you 2.

Answer (score 2):

The key point here is that the expression `bool + bool` is of type `int`, because no `operator+` would make sense with `bool`eans.

Considering that an `operator+` for `int`s exists, and that the Standard specifies at §4.5/6 that:

> A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int, with false becoming zero and true becoming one.

the prvalue of `true` is promoted to `1` and the prvalue of `false` is promoted to `0`.

This can be easily seen by the result of:

```
std::cout << (true + true);
```

which [is `2`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae148604daa27ae6).

In your first case the `decltype(t, u)` is obviously `bool` since both `t` and `u` are `bool`.
In the second case, instead the `decltype(t + u)`, for the above reasons, is `int`.