# Meaning of `decltype` with more than one argument

Tags: c++11

I have found [a `decltype`-related question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135697) in which
both the OP and the answerers seem to assume that
`decltype(t,u)` is something that depends on the types of both `t` and `u`.

I suppose that the intended meaning of the `decltype(t,u)`
in the linked question is that of a minimal type compatible with
both `t` and `u`, in some sense of *minimal* and *compatible*.
If it is meant like a *common type* as in §5(9) or in the definition
of `std::common_type` from §20.9.7.6(3), then the intended meaning would be
`decltype(true ? t : u)`.

However, it seems that C++11 defines only a one-argument `decltype`.
That said, the parser is specified to accept `decltype(` *expression* `)`
where *expression* can be a comma-separated list of *assignment-expression*.
Re-reading the specification of `decltype` from §7.1.6.2(4),
I have to interpret `decltype(t,u)` as `decltype((u))`.

Question: So what is `decltype(t,u)` actually? Am I missing something?

Edit: As answers converge on "this is the comma operator", I'd still like to see
your judgement on whether it's `decltype((u))` (a reference to the declared type) or `decltype(u)` (the declared type). I suspect the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comma here is the operator, not argument separator

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that. But am I right in my interpretation that this makes the returned type a *reference* to the declared type of `u`, that is, `decltype((u))` instead of `decltype(u)`?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Why should parentheses have to do smth with type of its content?

Comment: [`decltype` is special in that regard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).

Comment: Thanxs for info, I really didn't know it.

Comment: Well, I didn't search for confirmation from standard's draft, but it seems, that compilers (g++, vc, intel) agree with you: `decltype(t,u)` is `decltype( (u) )`

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: It is because decltype has two cases, one is for a direct reference to an object, decltype(var), decltype(obj.var) and decltype(ptr->var) and is the type of var. Everything else use the rules for expressions, where xvalue turns to T&&, lvalue turns to T& and everything else turns to T.

Answer (score 1):

it use the comma operator. so t,u is of type u.

Comment: Suppose `decltype(u)` yields some type `U` (the *declared* type of `u`), then `decltype((u))` and `decltype((t,u))` would be the type `U&`. So if we assume that `decltype(t,u)` is the same as `decltype((t,u))`, that should be the same as `decltype((u))`, not as `decltype(u)`, right?