# Enable a function template in C++ whenever an expression is undefined

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, sfinae

Can a function template be enabled whenever some expression is *un*defined (e.g., `x`of type `t` is *not* streamable to `std::cout`).  Something like

```
template<typename t>
auto f(const t &x) 
  -> typename enable_if_undefined<decltype(std::cout << x)>::type;
```

Using SFINAE, I only see how to enable if the expression is defined, but not how to do it if the expression is undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a helper which provides a boolean value you can reverse:

```
template<typename, typename=void>
struct has_cout
    : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_cout<T, decltype(std::cout << std::declval<T>(),void())>
    : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
auto f(const T& x) 
  -> typename std::enable_if<!has_cout<T>::value>::type;
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5104d0b012a6c2e0)

Comment: I actually want a slight generalization where the stream type is a template argument. Canonical for me would be to add it as another type in front. This fails, however, as streamable objects are now detected as non-streamable, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6765c6a4b6a21f3f). I suspected that the rvalue-ref returned by `std::declval<stream_t>()` might cause the problem, but then `std::move(std::cout) << 0` is valid.  Can you please also briefly explain what the `,void()` in the specialization of `has_cout` does?

Comment: @Xlea And for the second question about `,void()`: It makes sure that the `decltype` evaluates to `void`, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16044573/2073257) has more information.

Comment: @Xlea ou forgot the `stream_t` in the parameter list for the specialization and you need to add `&` to `declval<stream_t&>()` to get a non-const reference. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d27f10c7059a7480).

Comment: Stupid error, forgetting `stream_t` in the parameter list. Thanks a lot for your patience :)

Comment: Your ostream-generic-solution does not work for Visual C++ 2013. If I take your example and activate the line that shouldn't compile (and which it doesn't in g++), it actually does (with VC++): [here is the complete code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ec3ad4a4d8bca31). Any ideas what is going wrong? [Update: Same problem with the original example. Strangely, Intellisense actually "senses" an error at the line, but the compiler does not complain.]

Comment: @Xlea I don't know, I don't have Windows or VS. Maybe try replacing the `decltype(..., void())` with `typename std::enable_if<sizeof(...)!=0>::type`, but I really have no idea how to tame VS...

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'll try to figure it out when I have time.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class types, class=void>
  struct test_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct test_apply<Z,types<Ts...>,std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>>:
    std::true_type
  {};
};
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using test_apply=details::test_apply<Z,types<Ts...>>;
```

is the metaprogramming boilerplate.

Then the actual use-case specific code is really clean.  First, a simple `decltype` alias:

```
template<class X>
using cout_result = decltype( std::cout << std::declval<X>() );
```

and then we apply the test to it:

```
template<class X>
using can_cout_stream = test_apply< cout_result, X >;
```

the goal here is to decouple the metaprogramming boilerplate from the actual use.

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<!can_cout_stream<const T&>{}>
f(const T& x)
```

I liberally use C++14 features to make things a touch cleaner.  They can all be easily (re)implemented in C++11 if your compiler doesn't have them.

```
template<bool b, class T=void>
using enable_if_t=typename std::enable_if<b,T>::type;
template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;
```

should cover it.

Comment: This is Walter Brown's ["detection idiom"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4436.pdf), right?

Comment: @T.C. looks like.  My `test_apply` is close to his `is_detected_v`, almost.  I use `true_type` and `false_type` (well, types deriving from same), he uses `true` and `false`.  I hadn't seen that paper.  The `_t` thing where it returns some default type (like `void`) on failure seems strange to me.  Maybe it is useful?

Comment: The intention seems to be to allow you to check both the well-formedness of the thing and the type of the result at the same time. (Edit: ah, it's there for things like "`Alloc::pointer` if such a type exists; otherwise, `value_type*`".)

Comment: I do `apply_unless<bool, T, Z, Ts...>`, but I could see the utility in folding them together.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It certainly looks interesting, but I failed to get your suggestion working, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afb841a382454aac). What did I do wrongly?

Comment: @xlea `std::void_t` is C++1z.  `template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};template<class...Ts>usinf void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;` should replace it.  Maybe other issues, on phone, be back later.

Comment: That's it, it [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dafe2137b6f00a26). (I thought it was C++14, which is enabled in the above link.) Can you also hint on how to generalize so that the stream type can be passed as a template argument.

Comment: @xlea `cout_result` takes another parameter, does `declval<X>()` on it.  `can_cout_stream` takes an extra parameter, passes it on.  `enable_if` clause modified.  Function takes another template parameter, passes it into `enavle_if` clause to the `can_...` clause?