# Why decltype(a, b) is evaluated to a reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16044573/3980929), `ref` should be an `int`.

But for some reason it evaluated to `int&`, both in gcc and MSVC2015, while  `decltype(b)` is correctly evaluated to just `int`. Why so?

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
decltype(a, b) ref; // ref is int&
decltype(b) var;    // var is int
```

Comment: Perhaps `decltype(expr)` makes an lvalue-rvalue conversion (not ODR-used) of its expression, but, again, perhaps, the second expression, `b` doesn't do it due to the comma operator, so, `b` remains as a lvalue, being its corresponding type a reference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`a, b` is an expression. According to `decltype` rules for expressions, if result of the expression is an lvalue, type is going to be deduced as `T&`

> **7.1.6.2/4 Simple type specifiers [dcl.type.simple]**
>   For an expression e, the type denoted by decltype(e) is defined as follows:
>
> - if e is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized
>     class member access (5.2.5), decltype(e) is the type of the entity
>     named by e. If there is no such entity, or if e names a set of
>     overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
> - otherwise, if e is an xvalue, decltype(e) is T&&, where T is the type of e;
> - otherwise, if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T&, where T is the type
>     of e;
> - otherwise, decltype(e) is the type of e.

The confusing part about difference between *"type of the entity named by `e`"* and *"type of `e`"* is easy to understand with example:

If some entity `e` is declared as `int& e = x;`, then later, in expression *`e`*, *type of `e`* is `int`, and *type of the entity named by `e`* is `int&`. In short, *type of `e`* drops reference qualifiers.

Comment: `a` is an lvalue as well, however, `decltype(a)` is deduced as just `int`, not `int&`.

Comment: @Peregring-lk There is an specific rule for entity name. Standard quote in a second.

Comment: Can you produce a citation that "the type of `e`, where `int& e = x;`, is `int`"?

Comment: @Yakk 5/5 [expr] _If an expression initially has the type “reference to T”, the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis._ `e` is a primary expression (_id-expression_), so its type is adjusted to not contain any references. Hence point 1, which exist to avoid that in _id-expression_ s

Comment: For `decltype(b)` the important part is "if e is an **unparenthesized id-expression**". For `decltype(a, b)` the following dots. (See also the answer of @peppe)

Answer (score 8):

By the same reason for which `decltype((a)) ref` would declare `ref` as a reference (`int &`, instead of `int`).

`decltype` rules are different when they deal with expressions rather than entities. The value category of the `a, b` expression is a lvalue, hence `decltype(a, b)` yields `T&` -> `int &`.

See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype