# Decltype with two arguments modifies type

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I'm reading about `decltype` with multiple arguments and according to everyone else it just validates that all types are consistent and if so, completely discards all parameters but the last one. However it seems that passing another parameter does affect the return value:

```
  int i = 7;
  decltype(i) var = i;
  ++var;
  cout << i << endl; // prints '7', as I would expect
```

but:

```
  int i = 7;
  decltype(1, i) var = i;
  ++var;
  cout << i << endl; // prints '8' - apparently 'var' is now a reference to 'i'
```

Why is that?

Comment: `according to everyone else it just validates that all types are consistent and if so, completely discards all parameters but the last one` What is the source? I've never seen anyone claiming that before.

Comment: For instance, if I understood it correctly, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044514/what-is-decltype-with-two-arguments?rq=1. "A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right; the left expression is a discarded-value expression", "the result is of the same value category as its right operand"

Comment: Try `decltype((i))`

Comment: with `decltype((i))` it prints '8' in both cases.. So why is `decltype(i)` different from everything else? Or, in other words: why do `decltype(i)` and `decltype((i))` behave differently, but `decltype(i, j)` and `decltype((i, j))` behave the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at `,` which is an operator in C++ (comma operator). See [row 16](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Its declaration may looks like this:
`T2& operator,(const T& a, T2& b);`

So `a, b, c` is evaluate as `((a,b),c)`, `(b,c)`, `(c)`, which returns a reference to the return type of `c` (`a`, `b`, `c` can be expressions)

In your case `1, i` returns a reference to the last term, `i`. Hence the type is `int&`, so `decltype(1, i) var = i;` becomes `int& var = i;`

`(i)` is an expression, and it has return value which is a reference to `i` (`int&`)

Answer (score 4):

`decltype` does not take multiple arguments. You have passed it a single argument that happens to be a comma expression. If the last argument of the comma expression is just a variable, rather than introducing a temporary, the expression as a whole evaluates to a reference.

You can see the same thing without `decltype`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
  int i = 5;
  (1, i) = 10;
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When `decltype`'s argument is an immediate identifier (or class member access), it is treated in a special way - it denotes the exact declared type of the argument.

Otherwise, the argument of `decltype` is treated as an *expression*. It resolves to the type of that expression *adjusted in accordance with the value category of that expression*. E.g. if the expression is an *lvalue*, the type denoted by such `decltype` is a *reference* type.

In your case `decltype(i)` falls into the first category. So `decltype(i)` stands for `int`, since `i` is declared as an `int`.

Meanwhile your `decltype(1, i)` does not fit the first category. Its argument is treated as expression `1, i`. Since in C++ the result of such application of comma operator is an *lvalue*, this `decltype` denotes type `int &`.

For another example, `decltype((i))` would not fit the first category either because of the extra `()`. Since expression `(i)` is an lvalue, `decltype((i))` denotes type `int &`.